# If lattice in function

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that returns different values when the variable is in different ranges.

```
    nhpp_lambda <- function(t) {
  for (t in 1:365) {
    if (t >= "1" && t <= "59")
      lambda = 20.83
    else if (t >= "60" && t <= "151") 
      lambda = 11.02
    else if (t >= "152" && t <= "243")
      lambda = 11.68
    else if (t >= "244" && t <= "334")
      lambda = 26.41
    else if (t >= "335" && t <= "365")
      lambda = 20.83
  }
  return(lambda)
}
```

how come this doesn't work? it still just always returns 20.83??

Answer (score 2):

In the function you have defined you return the value of `lambda` *after* the loop has finished, and in the last iteration of the loop, the value is always 20.83. If you remove the loop, it will work, e.g.,

```
nhpp_lambda <- function (t) {
    if (t >= 1 && t <= 59)
        lambda = 20.83
    else if (t >= 60 && t <= 151) 
        lambda = 11.02
    else if (t >= 152 && t <= 243)
        lambda = 11.68
    else if (t >= 244 && t <= 334)
        lambda = 26.41
    else if (t >= 335 && t <= 365)
        lambda = 20.83
    return(lambda)
}

nhpp_lambda(5)
nhpp_lambda(55)
nhpp_lambda(120)
nhpp_lambda(285)
nhpp_lambda(340)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're taking $t$ as a function argument, but then defining $t$ through the loop $1:365$, so that $t$ cycles in values from $1,2,\dots,365$. Remove the for() loop, it serves no purpose.

Secondly, you're comparing a number $t$ to strings "1","59",etc. Remove the quoations, you should be comparing $t$ to integers not characters/strings. Here is the correct code

```
   nhpp_lambda <- function(t) {

    if (t >= 1 && t <= 59)
      lambda = 20.83
    else if (t >= 60 && t <= 151) 
      lambda = 11.02
    else if (t >= 152 && t <= 243)
      lambda = 11.68
    else if (t >= 244 && t <= 334)
      lambda = 26.41
    else if (t >= 335 && t <= 365)
      lambda = 20.83

  return(lambda)
}
```